# Looking for docs for trigger_event property in AdminDirectory.Users.list response object

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

While working with the Directory API I saw in the Users.list response a trigger_event field. I can't find any documentation on this. Is there any information on this property?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Users.list response a trigger_event field and your code for adding a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the `event` parameter in `Users.watch` (watch for changes in users list). The `event` parameter is a `string` "Events to watch for" and acceptable values are:

- "add": User Created Event
- "delete": User Deleted Event
- "makeAdmin": User Admin Status Change Event
- "undelete": User Undeleted Event
- "update": User Updated Event

in the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch).